# How to write half-open intervals as disjoint ones

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have a collection of half open intervals $(I_j, j \in \mathbb N)$ and I want to get a new collection $(J_j, j \in \mathbb N)$ out of the $I_j$ such that for $i \neq j$ $J_j \cap J_i = \emptyset$ and the Union of all $I_j$ is the same as the union of all $J_j$. I tried but I could not come up with something

half-open interval means interval of the form $[a,b)$

Please help and thanks

if it's not possible when there are infinite number of $I_i$, is it possible when there is only a finite number of them?

Comment: I guess all the intervals are in in the form (say) $(a,b]$ ? It's not true otherwise: pick $I_1=(a,b],\ I_2=[b,c)$. There is no subfamily $J_i$ with those two properties.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli no. they all take the same form $[a,b)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your intervals are indexed by the natural numbers, you could define the $J_j$ recursively. Here's the intuition: we'll go through the $I_j$ one-by-one. At each step, we define some number of half-open intervals $J_k$, such a way that the union of the $J_k$ defined so far is equal to the union of the $I_j$ considered so far. At each step, we might define more than one $J_k$, or maybe none at all; but we'll ensure that they're pairwise disjoint.

Here's a more formal approach. You can make it even more formal and prove that it works.

- Define $J_0=I_0$.
- For $n \ge 0$, suppose $I_0, \dots, I_n$ have been considered so far, and we've define $J_0, \dots, J_r$ in the process. Then the set
  $$I_{n+1} \setminus \bigcup_{k=1}^r J_k$$
  is a finite union of disjoint half-open intervals, since we're deleting a finite number of half-open intervals from a half-open interval. (Intuitively, if $a<c<d<b$, then $[a,b) \setminus [c,d) = [a,c) \cup [d,b)$, and you can extend this to a proof by induction of the above claim.) These new half-open intervals form the new $J_k$s.

You can then check that the $J_k$ are all pairwise disjoint, and their union is equal to the union of the $I_j$.

Answer (score 0):

Process the intervals in order. Whenever you see an $I_i$, remove from it all of the $J_j$s you have produced so far. Removing a *finite* number of half-open intervals from a single half-open interval breaks it into a finite number of smaller half-open intervals; append those to your list of $J_j$ intervals and continue with the nest $I_i$.

Comment: thanks. Can we just say let $J_0 = I_0$ and $J_n = I_n - (\cup_{j=0}^{n-1} I_j)$?

Comment: @madmatician: Not exactly, because $I_n-\cup_{j<n} I_j$ may not be a _single_ interval. For example if $I_0=[1,2)$ and $I_1=[0,3)$ you need to produce _two_ $J$s from $I_1$, namely $[0,1)$ and $[2,3)$.

Comment: Oh now I see. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's easy to check that $A = \{[a, b) : a, b \in \mathbb{R}\}$ is closed under intersection and complement.

Now if we consider $I_1, I_2$ we can get $$J_2 = I_1 \cap I_2$$ $$ J_1 \cup J_3 = (I_1 \cup I_2) \setminus J_2 : J_1 \cap J_3 = \emptyset$$ three disjoint sets (one of them possibly being empty) "representing" $I_1, I_2$.

Now for every other $I_{i>2}$ we repeat the operation with every $J_j \in J$. Note that if there are $n$ sets in $J$, they can create up to $n$ "holes" in $I_i$, so that $J$ must have no more than $2n+1$ sets at the end of the step. This way, $J$ remains countable.